# iTerm2: Adding vertical space between lines

Tags: terminal, spacing, iterm2

I am using `Iterm2` Terminal. I am having an issue setting vertical lines apart from each other as can be seen in the picture below. Is there a way to add vertical spacing between
the lines in iterm2? TIA!

[image]